# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API Key must not be empty

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a google maps API on my android project (inside a basic activity named BasicMapActivity.java) however I keep getting an error saying my API Key must not be empty.

My Logcat says the error is on this line of the code
`Places.initialize(BasicMapActivity.this, getString(R.string.google_maps_api));`

Inside my AndroidManifest, I have the meta-data tag with my google maps API key as follows:
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIza*********************dNq4" />`

which is enclosed inside the application tag.

Inside my strings.xml I have the string resource `<string name="google_maps_api" />`
which relates to my API key.

I seem to have done everything correctly so I'm not sure why I get this error. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
android:value="AIza*********************dNq4" />
```

I think you forgot to add api key

Strings.xml

```
<string name="google_maps_api">AIza*********************dNq4</string>
```